# Swipe to add overlay view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, swipe

I want to add a top overlaying view with a swipe to bottom and add a bottom overlaying view with a swipe to top. Using FragmentActivity.

How to show the overlay views?

```
________________________                  _______________________
|                      |                  |                      |
|                      |                  |   Overlay View       |
|                      |                  |   (Transparent bkg)  | 
|                      |                  |______________________|
|  (Swipe to bottom)   |      ===== >     |                      |
|                      |                  |                      |
|                      |                  |                      |
|                      |                  |                      |
|       Main View      |                  |    Main View         |
|                      |                  |                      |
|                      |                  |                      |
________________________                  ________________________
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement NavigationDrawer Top to Bottom instead of Left to right??

Answer (score 0):

You can swipe with the use of hand icon using  showcase library in Android

```
ShowcaseView sv;
ViewTarget target = new ViewTarget(R.id.yourviewid, this);
sv = ShowcaseView.insertShowcaseView(target, this, R.string.showcase_main_title, R.string.showcase_main_message, co);
```

From Top to bottom swipe

```
sv.animateGesture(0, 0, 0, -400);
```

and Bottom to top swipe

```
sv.animateGesture(0, 0, 0, 400);
```